# Django design decision for multiple databases

Tags: django

I have two a django site, on some of the pages data is coming from a postgresql database. Another set of pages are connected to a sqlite database. The tables are from two different sources so I cannot merge them but I need to merge them in one django site. What is the best practice for this:
should I merge the two in a django application so modifiying model.py,views.. or I should put them into different django applications with different models, view ?

Answer (score 0):

You can merge two apps into one instance, but then you won't be able to use default session and auth modules from django with models of one of it.

Good solution is to merge it into one project (so two apps can share some code and maybe some settings) but run it as 2 separate instances with 2 different settings loaded.

Also: you can just merge two databases, even if they are using different engines. Django has built in `dumpdata` and `loaddata` manage commands, you can use it to move data from one database to another.